# Is there a way to set SteamVR OpenXR to strict mode

Tags: steam-vr, openxr

**Background**

I'm having an issue where steamVR with an Oculus Quest 2 is being lenient with my use of OpenXR. For example

This is wrong (but works on steamVR)

```
    XrActionStateFloat actionState = XrActionStateFloat.create();
    XrActionStateGetInfo actionInfo = XrActionStateGetInfo.create();
    actionInfo.action(obtainActionHandle(action));

    XR10.xrGetActionStateFloat(xrSessionHandle, actionInfo, actionState);
```

This is right (I think)

```
    XrActionStateFloat actionState = XrActionStateFloat.create();
    actionState.type$Default();
    XrActionStateGetInfo actionInfo = XrActionStateGetInfo.create();
    actionInfo.type$Default();
    actionInfo.action(obtainActionHandle(action));

    XR10.xrGetActionStateFloat(xrSessionHandle, actionInfo, actionState);
```

SteamVR is I think assuming these `type$Default()` calls even if I don't make them. But other people's systems are returning -1 XR_ERROR_VALIDATION_FAILURE without them. This helpful behaviour is making debugging these problems hard

**Question**

Is there any way to switch SteamVR into a strict mode where these calls would aggressively fail?

---

N.b. the code here is a LWJGL binding for OpenXR